# Modelling an inventory control system with multiple item kinds

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Ok, I hope that my explanation is enough to understand my problem.

We have a company that make some products with determined raw material, this company also sells this raw material but as soon as it gets in the company they have to proceed with some analysis to be sure of the concentration of this material. Ok?

So we can sell some kinds of items, the raw material, the product resultant of the manufacturing of that material, the containers ( bottles, box, envelops ) for that material.

As all these kinds of item have such different information (e.g. a material has expiration date, the container has max ammount supported) we have splitted it into several tables for each type.

Then the inventory control has been separated in some tables that has the static information for each kind such as description, maximum dosis and etc. But I can't find the right way to find the items when it's bought, sold, transformed in other product or even available for selling.

I mean:

If I have two tables (lets say) for products

```
raw material ( id, description, maximum dosis)
manufactured material ( id, description, )
```

And a table to deal with the inventory

```
Inventory (id, analysis_report_id, weight, item_id ( referenced by which of those 2 tables? )
```

Will I have to use a field for each table and look for which field is filled and then join every product kind table when searching for items in inventory?

I can go more in depth if it stills blurred to understand

(I'm using postgreSQL BTW).

Should I reformulate my question or it is really a complex question?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, I'd factor this into 4 tables:

```
Item (ItemID, Description, Type)
RawMaterialItem(RawMaterialItemID, maximumDosis, ItemID)

Inventory (id, analysis_report_id, weight, item_id )
```

The Item table effectively contains all common fields, shared by RawMaterial and ManufacturedMaterial; columns that are unique to Material tables get stored in their own tables, with a foreign key to the Item table. The Type column in the Item table is an indicator of the item type - in your example, it would be either RawMaterial or ManufacturedMaterial.

To get all the data for a given item, you'd look at the type column, and join on the relevant table. 
This is pretty ugly - for the alternatives, look at Craig Larman's book "Applying UML and Patterns".

This way, your Inventory table joins to just one table - Item.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to see the details of each "Material" table ? how would I know which table should I join? Let's say: Item( 50, 'alcohol') would be joined to RawMaterialItem(35, 2ml, 50) but Item (51, 'alcohol bottles') would join to ContainerItem ( 70, 1un, 51) . Then for listing information for 1 item I would have to join all tables and then discover which table has that ItemID?

Comment: "To get all the data for a given item, you'd look at the type column, and join on the relevant table. This is pretty ugly - for the alternatives, look at Craig Larman's book "Applying UML and Patterns"." 
Yes, that's ugly... and that was what I was trying to avoid... but it seems that there is no other option...

Comment: Larman describes 2 alternatives - one is to have all possible columns in the "item" table, which gets confusing very quickly, and the other is to have specific tables for each sub-type, which makes referential integrity really hard. One thing you could do with my proposal is to create views to represent the subtypes - you could at least use those for queries, if not for data modifications...